# Using oracle seq generator in Informatica Mapping

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter

My source and target are oracle table.I am trying to create a scd type 2 mapping and its working fine when using informatica sequence generator transformation to create dimension id.

But when i try to keep the dimension id port unconnected, because I have a sequence defined for that column at data base level, the session fails while  loading target stating the table/view doesn't exist.
The dimension id column is defined as follow in table ddl -

dim_id number default sequence_name.nextval not null

It's because of this table/view doesn't exist error that I am not able to debug the mapping.I am not changing anything else in the mapping, just removing the seq gen transformation, and it starts failing.

Comment: May be permission issue on the object. Try to see if the proper permissions are present.

Comment: doubt - when does it work?  with sequence generator - or without? Did you check if you have RW permission on target/source?